# Turning Vue route parameters into integers

Tags: function, vue.js, dynamic, parameters, routes

I wanted to create my portfolio with Vue. I'm stuck with trying to turn the route params from a string into an id.

In the home page, my portfolio items are listed (doing this static-ally and using data objects and not getting from a database). When you click on them, route params take their id and it directs to /portfolio/1, /portfolio/2, and so on. This page then dynamically changes according to the data of that object.

There's also a pagination in this page (Next Project and Previous Project). Because I use their id as a parameter, I wanted to increment or decrement the ID on click so that it would lead to the next or previous project but I found out that the params are read as a string and not an integer, thus ending up with /portfolio/11 or /portfolio/21.

How can I implement this?

The code I've tried so far is as follows:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Project', params: { id: `${previousFolio}` } }">
   <b-button class="project-nav-button">
      <img src="@/assets/icon-arrow-back.svg" alt="previous project button" class="previous"/>
      <p>Previous Project</p>
   </b-button>
</router-link>

<router-link :to="{ name: 'Project', params: { id: nextFolio } }">
   <b-button class="project-nav-button">
      <p>Next Project</p>
      <img src="@/assets/icon-arrow-next.svg" alt="next project button" class="next"/>
   </b-button>
</router-link>
```

```
data() {
    return {
        folioId: this.$route.params.id,
        folios: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Project Title 1"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Project Title 2"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Project Title 3"
        }
        ]
     };
  },

computed: {
        currentFolio: function() {
            let folioId = this.$route.params.id;
            return this.folios.filter(function (folio) {
                return folio.id == folioId;
        })
        },

        nextFolio: function() {
             let currentFolioId = this.$route.params.id;
             currentFolioId = parseInt(currentFolioId);
             return currentFolioId++;
             console.log(currentFolioId);
        },

        previousFolio: function() {
             let folioId = this.$route.params.id;
             return folioId--;
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `parseInt()` to convert it to integer

```
let folioId = parseInt(this.$route.params.id);
```